# Rocket Engine Failure Rate

Tags: rockets, engines, failure

I am a reciprocating engine machinist and understand that rocket engines are *much much* more complex.  But I am curious why they have such a high failure rate.  Even modern rockets are designed to compensate for and do experience high engine failure rates whilst the modern jet engine has a failure rate of <.001%.

What is the greatest point of failure  **1)fuel supply** or **2)engine component failure?**

Of engine components, what is the single greatest point of failure?  I would suspect the turbopumps.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21):

Booster rocket engines operate at enormously higher propellant flow rates, pressures, and temperatures than reciprocating or jet engines. The thermal gradients alone are savage: The Space Shuttle Main Engine (SSME) took in liquid hydrogen at 37 deg R (~ 20 K) while a few feet away, the combustion chamber has 6000 deg R (~ 3000 K) gas in it.

I don't have info on current engines, but you might be interested in this spreadsheet I made about the major failures of the SSME. Most occurred during ground testing.

[image]

For this answer, I sorted it by the "brief description". You can see that blade failures in the turbopumps and problems with the liquid oxygen posts (part of the main combustion chamber injector) dominate.

The terminology used in the spreadsheet is a bit opaque I'm afraid, but the documents listed along the top are mostly available on NASA NTRS, except for the key one, AL-TR-89-013, which you can get here: https://apps.dtic.mil/sti/pdfs/ADA213600.pdf

The video mentioned is available on youtube:

Essential acronymology:

- ASI - Augmented Spark Igniter
- CCV - Chamber Coolant Valve aka Coolant
  Control Valve
- FPB - Fuel PreBurner
- HEX - Heat EXchanger
- HPFP - High
  Pressure Fuel Pump
- HPFT - High Pressure Fuel Turbine
- HPFTP - High
  Pressure Fuel TurboPump
- HPOT - High Pressure Oxygen Turbine
- HPOTP -
  High Pressure Oxygen TurboPump
- LOX - Liquid OXygen
- MCC - Main
  Combustion Chamber
- MFV - Main Fuel Valve
- MOV - Main Oxidizer Valve
- OPB - Oxidizer PreBurner

Comment: As another data point, Elon Musk recently tweeted that the chamber walls of the Raptor 3 combustion chamber may possibly experience the highest heat flux of any human-made artifact. (Although one might need to constrain that to *sustained* heat flux, otherwise surely one would be beaten by the housing of a thermonuclear warhead or something like that.)

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen someone actually use Rankine for temperature before.

Comment: @fyrepenguin that's what we used in the Shuttle program. https://i.imgur.com/v1hIIVA.png

Comment: @JörgWMittag At this point, if Musk tweets "the sky is blue", my response is going to be _[citation needed]_.

Comment: @RussellBorogove lol

Comment: Thanks for that tidbit, @OrganicMarble, I now have a real-life recent-ish example of people using Rankine

Comment: @fyrepenguin I was going to ask. At least OM gave us Kelvin as well.

Comment: @fyrepenguin More recently, the FAA used it for the raptor exhaust plume temperature https://www.faa.gov/space/stakeholder_engagement/spacex_starship/media/Appendix_G_Exhaust_Plume_Calculations.pdf (see figure 6 on page 9)

Comment: @Speedphoenix thanks for a really interesting link.

Comment: Thanks, @Speedphoenix. I did notice though … Fig 1 is in Kelvin while Fig 6 is in Rankine … *whyyyyy*

Answer (score 1):

Rocket engines are optimized for minimum mass and maximum performance. Designers seek to create a [Deacon's Masterpiece](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Deacon%27s_Masterpiece). Every component is designed to operate close to its safe limit. But what *is* that limit, really? No theory can tell you precisely. Thus, some components will have better real-life safety factors than others. Which ones? Unpredictable. I expect that the weakest part is different for every design.